# Getting the line_items from Stripe webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a script that retrieves a webhook event that was working well. With stripe new API, the sku of my product doesn't show anymore. Until now, I was getting the webhook event in PHP like this :

```
$event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload,
    $sig_header,
    $secretEndpoint
);
```

and then

```
$event->data->object->display_items[0]->sku->id
```

As I'm reading the documentation, I think I have to expand the line_items object (don't see anything related to line_items in webhook request btw) : https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=php

But don't understand how to implement this in my PHP enpoint.

For further informations, the payment is made on a Checkout page, the button that redirect to this page is the classic shortcode given by Stripe, and contains the sku of my products :

```
 stripe.redirectToCheckout({
 lineItems: [{
 price: 'sku_MB4fzaySUCJC9T',
 quantity: 1
 }],
 mode: 'payment',
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what object you are trying to retrieve `line_items` from so I'm going to assume it's a [`Checkout Session object`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object).  This answer will still apply if that is not correct but the API you need to hit will be different.

So, webhook events do not support [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) by themselves.  You will need to [retrieve the object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) from the API using the ID in the `$event->data->object->id`.  This is where you can specify that you want to expand the [`line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=php#checkout_session_object-line_items).

I tested the code below both with and without the expansion parameter and can confirm the `line_items` property is returned when passing the `expand` parameter:

```php
$checkout = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
    $checkoutId,
    ['expand' => ['line_items']]
);

echo $checkout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually just found what's happening.

I'm still using stripe API version from 2018, this can be changed manually on stripe dashboard.

That being said, when you create a new product in Stripe, the shorcode provided is a shorcode that fits the most recent version of the API,

My endpoint works well with the older type of shortcode :

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
items: [{sku: 'sku_MB1fzaySUCJC9T',
quantity: 1}],
```

but not with the new one :

```
 stripe.redirectToCheckout({
 lineItems: [{
 price: 'sku_MB1fzaySUCJC9T',
 quantity: 1
 }],
 mode: 'payment',
```

Just modified to use the old fashion way.